# Refactoring small F# function

Tags: .net, f#, refactoring

I've made the following F# function that will get me an url from the html contents of a web page:

```
let getPicUrl (urlContents : string) =
  let START_TOKEN = "jpg_url="
  let startIndex = urlContents.IndexOf(START_TOKEN)
  let endIndex = urlContents.IndexOf("&amp", startIndex)
  let s = startIndex + START_TOKEN.Length
  let l = endIndex-startIndex-START_TOKEN.Length

  urlContents.Substring(s, l)
```

what the last line, `urlContents.Substring(s, l)`, actually needs is only `s` and `l`, so I was wondering whether I could refactor parts of this function into some internal functions so I'd let my intentions be clearer. Ideally `getPicUrl` would only have 2 `let` instructions, `s` and `l`, and all the others would be internal definitions to those `let` instructions. If this can in any way be achieved or not is another story..

The only obvious way I can think at the moment to improve the above code would be to switch `endIndex` of place so we'd have

```
let getPicUrl (urlContents : string) =
  let START_TOKEN = "jpg_url="
  let startIndex = urlContents.IndexOf(START_TOKEN)
  let s = startIndex + START_TOKEN.Length
  let l =
    let endIndex = urlContents.IndexOf("&amp", startIndex)
    endIndex-startIndex-START_TOKEN.Length

  urlContents.Substring(s, l)
```

but I keep wondering if there'd be a clearer way of organizing this function's `let` definitions.

Comment: Voting to move this to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Didn't even know that SE site existed :o

Comment: Haha, me neither until I had my question closed due to it

Comment: I'd prefer to have this question here, though. There doesn't seem to be a lot of traffic over there :'(

Comment: I know the feeling. I got good responses over there though and the traffic will never increase if SO takes all the questions belonging there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your function is buggy. A non-matching string will make it grumpy.

I like regexes for this sort of thing. With this active pattern:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let (|Regex|_|) pattern input =
  let m = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
  if m.Success then Some(List.tail [for g in m.Groups -> g.Value])
  else None
```

you can do:

```
let tryGetPicUrl = function
  | Regex @"jpg_url=([^&]+)&amp" [url] -> Some url
  | _ -> None
```

You could also turn your original approach into an active pattern:

```
let (|Between|_|) (prefix:string) (suffix:string) (value:string) =
  match value.IndexOf(prefix) with
  | -1 -> None
  | s ->
    let n = s + prefix.Length + 1
    match value.IndexOf(suffix, n) with
    | -1 -> None
    | e -> Some (value.Substring(n, e - n))
```

and do:

```
let tryGetPicUrl = function
  | Between "jpg_url" "&amp" url -> Some url
  | _ -> None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write it this way:

```
let getPicUrl (urlContents : string) =
  let s =
    let START_TOKEN = "jpg_url="
    let startIndex = urlContents.IndexOf(START_TOKEN)
    startIndex + START_TOKEN.Length
  let l =
    let endIndex = urlContents.IndexOf("&amp", s)
    endIndex-s

  urlContents.Substring(s, l)
```

Comment: I like this answer.  Not knowing F# very well, this is the most readable answer right now.

Comment: His function is buggy. That's why I somewhat rewrote it.

Comment: @Daniel, what do you mean? What is the bug?

Comment: That correctly throws an exception. The message could be more descriptive, but that's it. If you know passing invalid string is an error, you should treat it that way (only the OP can know whether this is the case).

Comment: @svick: Yes, what is "exceptional" is subjective. Out of habit, I would have a hard time ignoring the return value of a function, even for throw-away code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use split method of string (I hope the string is not too long as that would be a performance hit) and use option type to indicate whether the URL was found or not.

```
let getPicUrl (urlContents : string) =
    let splitAndGet n (sep:string) (str:string) = 
        let spl = str.Split([|sep|],StringSplitOptions.None)
        match spl.Length with
        | x when x > n -> Some (spl.[n])
        | _ -> None 
    match urlContents |> splitAndGet 1 "jpg_url=" with
    | Some str -> str |> splitAndGet 0 "&amp"
    | _ -> None
```